# Mip map artifacts

Tags: unity, textures, blender, blending, mipmaps

I have created a texture in Blender in texture paint mode. [image: Main]

Then I have started to add some details for side and corner texture. They are primarily height maps.

[image: Side]

[image: Corner]

I had some minor pixels being a different colour on the edges (don't know why they appeared). So I painted them out with colour picker. If you look at the texture (the one that I cleaned up is third) there shouldn't be any artifacts or missing pixels. Though, data from them was somehow stored inside the texture on different layer or what I don't understand that. As a result it created weird pixels that appear only on mip maps.
[image: Mip Map]

Notice that original texture doesn't have these problems.
[image: Original]

If I use image in texture on a displacement modifier in blender it uses that data to displace the mesh which is totally weird for me because I have painted out those pixels. Did I do something wrong? I have tried all the blending modes in Blender. I have tried to do everything I thought of in Krita, Paint, Paint3D.. I have changed the colours, erased the alpha, erased the colour and painted over and over again. Nothing helps. Even if the colour is set to bump the mesh, it uses the data normally but as soon as I change it back to neutral colour it uses wrong data again.

[image: Blender]

Result in Unity.[image: Result]

Original texture result
[image: Original result]

All the settings are the same.

Comment: It looks like it's repeating, can you set it to clamp instead? Perhaps you need to add padding to the edges.

Comment: @Sidar https://prnt.sc/ic2bh7 - didn't help, the original texture has Wrap Mode - Repeat and it's showing fine.

Comment: @Sidar I checked that and you were right, but it doesn't solve the problem. I have solved it by adding a margin to UVs but the mip maps don't care about Clamp.

Comment: @Sidar Thanks for your help, now I know where to look for the solution. It looks like you shouldn't use full width of the texture, so it's better to always leave some margin. You can leave your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I wonder if compression artifacts play a part. See if [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6D5tBEjS-N0) helps at all.

Comment: @sambler Didn't know about that. Thank you for this video. I will try it and give an update. Might take a little bit time. I need to understand how engines, shaders and textures work in more depth because otherwise I will encounter problems like this all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need some padding/margins in your texture so it doesn't bleed from edge to edge.

Edit:

I should probably elaborate, Ill probably come back to this ( can't right now ). So if someone else can elaborate that would be cool too.

Answer (score -2):

It is happening because of the mesh quality. Use a subsurf modifier or subdivide the plane

Comment: Not possible, it's a quad with UV mapping. It's just shader using values that are being projected on surface.